# Rotating a moving Object along a path in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've created a static background in one layer of a canvas element and then trying to move the rectangular object that I've created to go through the cylinder, pipe and then it should fall into the small cylinder at the end of the pipe. I'm able to move it along a straight line but I have to rotate the object (say -25 degrees) and then make it travel horizontally (180 degrees, when it is travelling in y direction inside the pipe).
The code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>

</head>
<body>

<section>
<div id="canvasesdiv" style="position:relative; width:650px; height:600px">
<canvas id="layer1"
style="z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
" height="600px" width="650">
</canvas>

<canvas id="layer2"
style="z-index: 2;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
" height="600px" width="650">
</canvas>
</div>

<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>

<script type="text/javascript">



var requestId = 0;
var animationStartTime=0;
var speed=1;
var posX=160;  //for cylinder
var posY=posX+50;  //for cylinder 
var x=160; //for packets  
var y=230; //for packetsvar time=1000;
//var time=1000;
var layer1;
var layer2;
var ctx;
var ctx2;

var pack=setInterval(drawPacket,1500);

function packet(){
layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
ctx = layer1.getContext("2d");

layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");
window.onload=drawScreen();

}

function animate() {
ctx2.clearRect(0,0,layer2.width,layer2.height);
requestAnimationFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame
                ;  
requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

anime();
}

function anime(){
if ( x>=0 || x<=445){
drawPacket();
x+=speed;
}

if( posXX==445 && posYY==230){
y+=-speed;
}}

function drawPacket(){
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.clearRect(0,0,layer2.width,layer2.height);
ctx2.rect(x,y, 10, 30);
ctx2.closePath();
ctx2.stroke();
ctx2.restore();
}

function redrawPacket(){
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.clearRect(0,0,layer2.width,layer2.height);
ctx2.rotate( (Math.PI / 180) * -25);  //rotate 25 degrees.
ctx2.rect(x,y, 10, 30);
ctx2.closePath();
ctx2.stroke();
}

function start() {
requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function stop() {
  if (requestId)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
  requestId = 0;
}

function  drawScreen() {

ctx.beginPath();
{
//top line
ctx.moveTo(250,215);
ctx.lineTo(390,215);


//bottom line
ctx.moveTo(250,315);
ctx.lineTo(390,315);

//front  curve
ctx.moveTo(230,230);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(250,200,269,230);

//bottom curve
ctx.moveTo(230,300);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(250,330,268,300);


//front arc joining top and bottom opp curve
ctx.moveTo(230,230);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(214,265,230,300);


//front opp arc joining top and bottom opp curve
ctx.moveTo(269,230);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(286,265,268,300);

//ctx.moveTo(230,230);
//ctx.fillRect(230,230,188.80,170);

//back small top curve
ctx.moveTo(390,215);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(407,218,414,230);

//back small bottom curve
ctx.moveTo(390,315);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(405,314,414,300);

//back arc
ctx.moveTo(414,230);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(435,263,414,300);

ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}

ctx.beginPath();

{
//First Cylinder
//First cylinder 1st line of rect
ctx.moveTo(574,130);
ctx.lineTo(574,195);

//First cylinder opp line of rect
ctx.moveTo(614,130);
ctx.lineTo(614,195);

//First cylinder bottom arc
ctx.moveTo(574,195);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(594,205,614,195);

//First cylinder top-top arc
ctx.moveTo(574,130);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(594,119,614,130);

//First cylinder top-bottom arc
ctx.moveTo(574,130);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(594,142,614,130);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}

ctx.beginPath();
{
//Second Cylinder
//Second cylinder 1st line of rect
ctx.moveTo(574,428);
ctx.lineTo(574,493);

//Second cylinder opp line of rect
ctx.moveTo(614,428);
ctx.lineTo(614,493);

//drawellipse(574,428,10,2,0.5) 

//Second cylinder bottom arc
ctx.moveTo(574,493);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(594,503,614,493);

//Second cylinder top-top arc
ctx.moveTo(574,428);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(594,417,614,428);

//Second cylinder top-bottom arc
ctx.moveTo(574,428);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(594,440,614,428);       
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}


ctx.beginPath();

{
//Pipe to cylinder 1
//top line from main cylinder
ctx.moveTo(408,222);
ctx.lineTo(436,222);

//left line from main cylinder
ctx.moveTo(436,222);
ctx.lineTo(436,32);

//bottom line from main cylinder
ctx.moveTo(423,266);
ctx.lineTo(486,266);

//right line from main cylinder
ctx.moveTo(486,266);
ctx.lineTo(486,82);

//top line from left line
ctx.moveTo(436,32);
ctx.lineTo(619,32);

//bottom line from right line
ctx.moveTo(486,82);
ctx.lineTo(566,82);

//drop line to cylinder right
ctx.moveTo(619,32);
ctx.lineTo(619,112);

//drop line to cylinder left
ctx.moveTo(566,82);
ctx.lineTo(566,112);
//closing the pipe
ctx.moveTo(566,112);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(592,128,619,112);
ctx.moveTo(566,112);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(592,96,619,112);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}
}
packet();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me solve this problem..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to animate an object along a path is to calculate polypoints along that path.

Then for each animation loop, you advance the object to the next polypoint.

Here is a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RtXq6/

**For example, your cylinder-tube path might have line segments that are defined like this:**

```
var pathArray=[]
pathArray.push({x:25, y:250});
pathArray.push({x:150,y:250});
pathArray.push({x:150,y:50});
pathArray.push({x:250,y:50});
pathArray.push({x:250,y:100});
```

**You can calculate polypoints along that series of line segments like this:**

```
function makePolyPoints(pathArray){

    var points=[];

    for(var i=1;i<pathArray.length;i++){
        var startPt=pathArray[i-1];
        var endPt=pathArray[i];
        var dx = endPt.x-startPt.x;
        var dy = endPt.y-startPt.y;
        for(var n=0;n<=100;n++){
            var x= startPt.x + dx * n/100;
            var y= startPt.y + dy * n/100;
            points.push({x:x,y:y});
        }
    }
    return(points);
}
```

**Then you can animate your object along each polypoint of the path like this:**

```
        var width=15;
        var height=30;
        var position=0;
        var speed=2;
        var rotation=0;
        var rotationSpeed=Math.PI/60;
        animate();

        var fps = 60;
        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimFrame(animate);

                // calc new position
                position+=speed;
                if(position>polypoints.length-1){
                    return;
                }
                var pt=polypoints[position];

                rotation+=rotationSpeed;

                // draw
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
                ctx.rotate(rotation);
                ctx.rect(-width/2,-height/2,15,30);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();        
                ctx.restore();

            }, 1000 / fps);
        }
```

This example creates 100 polypoints along each of the 5 line segments.  Because each line segment is a different length, the animation will be faster for longer line segments and slower for shorter line segments.

If you want a more evenly paced animation, you can calculate fewer than 100 polypoints on the shorter line segments (the longest line line will have 100 polypoints--the shorter lines will have proportionally fewer polypoints)  You can determine how many polypoints per line by taking the length ratio of any shorter line versus the longest line.

Comment: Thank you so much...Now it works. I completed my project successfully :)

Comment: how can the same be achieved with bezier paths?

Comment: @Anubhav.  You can use De Casteljau's algorithm to plot points along each Bezier Curve. Cheers!